# strtotime and "better readability"

Tags: php, yii, strtotime

I'm a newbie using a book to learn the Yii php framework. It has this line of code and the book explains that they have taken the time to format the date for better readability

```
$lastLogin = strtotime($user->last_login_time);
```

However, from looking at the manual, I thought that the output of `strtotime` is a unix timestamp. If that's correct, how could that be better readability?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

Their stance on readability is that the time is stored internally as readable.

Go on and try `print_r($user);` and see what happens :)

Answer (score 0):

For the other way round use [strftime()](http://php.net/strftime)